# Moving Joomla + Virtuemart Installation

Tags: joomla, installation, virtuemart

I have simply downloaded my joomla+virtuemart files from the server and the mysql file and set up a db, inserted the imported rows and updated the config.php file in joomla.
However, even after updating the configuration.php when I open my joomla installation my site (on the actual webhost opens up) as in example.com
I wanted it to work on localhost/joomla (where the downloaded files and modified configuaration resides).
I also have DELETED the .htaccess files to remove any redirections.
I also updated the virtue mart administratior/components/com_virtumart/virtuemark.cfg.php file's URL and secure url variables.

No matter what I do, it still opens up the example.com site instead of the localhost/joomla app directory

Any help is much appreciated.
Running on joomla 1.5.1

I thought it might be DB related so I exported the data to a php file through phpmyadmin and ran a check on example.com even on the sql file. But it didn't show up any either

Cheers
Dileep

Comment: what are you using as a localhost? what PHP version does it use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dileep,

There is an addon for migrating Joomla (and it's extensions) that we've had great success with in the past. I've moved sites dozens of times and to date, have had no big problems

It's called [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html). There are free and paid versions and (last I checked) there are legacy versions still there for 1.5.x.

Combined with a package called Kickstart, you can backup and restore the entire site from one server to another with just a few clicks.
The website is akeebabackup dot com.

Migrating by hand, I've had mixed results. Use this software and you'll avoid those headaches.